# Not Found: /media/ 404 77 Django production - ASGI Digital Ocean

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I've tried everything but my `media` folder profile pic images still aren't appearing. They look like this on the webpage.

[image: broken]

I'm in production for my Django 2.1 app, using Digital Ocean running a ASGI server (as I'm using `channels`).

My `media` folder is located in my root folder (same level as `manage.py`).

The error being given is

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx - - [23/Feb/2019:17:23:49] "GET /media/profile_pics/avril.jpg" 404 77
```

But that is the correct path and the image is located there. All of my `static` files are rendering fine.

my settings.py

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'sobr.routing.application'

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'appname/static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080')],
        },
    },
}
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

nginx upstream

```
   location /static/ {
        root /home/user/appname/src/appname;
    }

    location /media/  {
        alias /home/user/appname/src/appname/media;
    }
```

traceback

```
2019-02-24 18:42:02,932 WARNING  Not Found: /media/profile_pics/girl.jpg
2019-02-24 18:42:02,934 WARNING  Not Found: /media/profile_pics/avril.jpg
2019-02-24 18:42:02,933 WARNING  Not Found: /media/profile_pics/man.jpg
xx.141.198.14:59401 - - [24/Feb/2019:18:42:03] "GET /media/profile_pics/brad_2G59aPW.jpg" 404 77
xx.141.198.14:59400 - - [24/Feb/2019:18:42:03] "GET /media/profile_pics/girl.jpg" 404 77
xx.141.198.14:59402 - - [24/Feb/2019:18:42:03] "GET /media/profile_pics/avril.jpg" 404 77
xx.141.198.14:59399 - - [24/Feb/2019:18:42:03] "GET /media/profile_pics/man.jpg" 404 77
xx.141.198.14:59404 - - [24/Feb/2019:18:42:03] "GET /static/fonts/PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf" 304 -
xx.141.198.14:59405 - - [24/Feb/2019:18:42:03] "GET /static/fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf" 304 -
xx.141.198.14:59401 - - [24/Feb/2019:18:42:03] "GET /static/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf" 304 -
```

Comment: If you are in production, the `settings.DEBUG` is likely (hopefully) set to `False`, hence the body of the `if` is never executed.

Comment: Ah okay, yes that makes a lot of sense. And yes it is set to `False`. How should I word it in order to account for that? Take out the if and leave it as `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`?

Comment: And how you have done in templates?

Comment: @Debendra I've just updated my question to show templates.

Comment: I mean the html jinja template.

Comment: Ah my apologies `src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.image.url }}"`

Comment: Please add full path (on drive) for that file.

Comment: Full path on vm is `/home/user/appname/src/appname/media/profile_pics` Full path on local computer is `/Users/user/dev/appname/src/appname/media/profile_pics`

Comment: `location /media/` settings do not match this path. It should be `alias /home/user/appname/src/appname/media`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I meant to update it above but I changed it to that earlier and the images still don't show. I have updated it above.

Comment: Did you restart nginx after changing config? Since you're on prod, I guess DEBUG is False and django has nothing to do with this issue. Check files and folders names and existence on prod one more time. Try serving _another_ folder with dummy files (like `1.txt`) with nginx - are they accessible?

Comment: Yes I have restarted nginx everytime I've made a change and still nothing and yes debug is false. So as an example, set the `location /media/` settings on the server config to a different path with a different file and see if it picks up on it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup server properly? Please check your nginx upstream  for media file as below.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    ............

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/project/staticfiles/;
    }
    location /media/ {
            alias /home/project/media/;
    }
.........



}
```

Comment: Yes I've added that in my question, it seems to be set up correctly.

Comment: Actually I'm going to try and add `/staticfiles/` and `media` on the end and see.

Comment: Nothing happens, it's still not showing the images in the `/media/` folder

Comment: try these steps

- slash after media
- have you restart nginx  and supervisor after changes.
- from your settings ASGI_APPLICATION = 'sobr.routing.application'
- if sobr is your root folder(Not sure though if it is root folder). why not your media file path is  something similar like this /home/user/sobr/media/

Comment: Try this (not in if settings.DEBUG:)    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT). Move outside of settings.DEBUG

Comment: Yes I have restarted nginx after every change, I've just added a trailing slash and nothing changes. I have my root folder inside of an `src` folder. Like `home/users/appname/src/appname/` then on that last `appname` level there is `manage.py` `media` `staticfiles` and all the apps

Comment: I will try moving it outside.

Comment: I moved it outside and still nothing :(

Comment: I don't understand because it's having no problem finding the `static` files?

Comment: Have you looked at this one from documentation  [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) If you want to use {{ MEDIA_URL }} in your templates, add 'django.template.context_processors.media' in the 'context_processors' option of TEMPLATES.

Comment: with your current existing setting.
>>> Try Using only. {{ profile.image.url }} instead of {{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.image.url }}

Comment: When I change debug to `True` (on my local machine not on the production server) the `media` displays, but when `debug=false` the media does not display. I've added in `django.template.context_processors.media` and also tried taking out `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` but images still don't display.

Comment: When debug=false may be you do not have urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

So try to append with  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) with rest of your urlpatterns

Comment: So I've tried adding `re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),` into urlpatterns but nothing still.

Comment: Django docs say however `you should serve these files in production using a real front-end web server` which the nginx config should be doing and the paths are clearly right because when `debug=True` the `/media/` works fine. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development

Comment: The console is now showing `[2019/02/24 18:22:38] HTTP GET /media//media/profile_pics/man.jpg 404 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:59193]` which it was never showing before so it is now looking in the wrong path it seems

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is now looking for the `media` folder inside of a non-existent app called `media`?

Comment: It was that line that I copied and pasted from the docs above `django.template.context_processors.media` that messed the file path up for some reason.

Comment: I've added majority of the traceback above.